# Ionic Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "." when importing a service provider

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, webpack, ionic3

I am trying to import a new service provider that I just created after pulling from the latest branch in my ionic app.

When I try to import this line of code:

```
import { AuthServiceProvider } from '../providers/auth-service'
```

in **app.module.ts** I always got an error saying that:

> ```
> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "."
>     at webpackMissingModule (index.js:3)
>     at e.code (index.js:3)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:9)
>     at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 62d6a5897825ac327001:54)
>     at Object.690 (slide.transition.ts:67)
>     at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 62d6a5897825ac327001:54)
>     at Object.495 (main.js:1885)
>     at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 62d6a5897825ac327001:54)
>     at Object.487 (notification-api.ts:6)
>     at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 62d6a5897825ac327001:54)
> ```

But take note that I am also importing another service from my provider that is working perfectly.

Here is the code of my **auth-service.ts** below.

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular/umd';

/*
  Generated class for the AuthServiceProvider provider.

  See https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection for more info on providers
  and Angular DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class AuthServiceProvider {

  public isLoggedIn = false;

  constructor(
    public http: HttpClient,
    private events: Events
  ) {
    console.log('Hello AuthServiceProvider Provider');

    events.subscribe('user:logged-in', (user) => {
      this.isLoggedIn = true;
      console.log('Welcome', user);
    });
  }

}
```

I won't show my code in my **app.module.ts** because it is bombarded by import plugins and other providers.

Here is my **ionic info**

```
cli packages: (/usr/lib/node_modules)

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0 browser 5.0.3
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
Node              : v6.12.2
npm               : 4.6.1 
OS                : Linux 4.13
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : /home/clifford/Android/Sdk
```

So why I am having an error in that specific service provider compare to other providers which are just the same?

Any thoughts?

Appreciate if someone could help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I finally figure it out to solve the problem. The error occurs when I import the [events](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/) from `ionic-angular`.

So instead of: `import { Events } from 'ionic-angular/umd';`

Just remove the **umd** at the end. I don't know why it happened because I am using auto import from my vs code.

Comment: Worked for me when importing ModalController.

Comment: Have opened an issue in vscode https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/52786. Its probably an issue with the auto import

Answer (score 0):

I changed `import { Events } from 'ionic-angular/umd';` to `import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';`. I was using "typescript": "~2.6.2". I tried to change the version of typescript and I have heard that typescript 3.1 can be fix in some cases. In my case once i went higher than typescript 2.8.0 I started getting other issues related to ionic. At the end the above fix works, and I think this is more a ionic framework issue.