# Can not find module "." Ionic 3 , WebPacketMissing Error in vendor.js

Tags: ionic3

I am facing this issue after creating a provider in an ionic application.
After adding provider in application vendor.js throws issue with WebPacket Missing.

Error: Cannot find module "."

```
at webpackMissingModule (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:158013:69)
at e.code (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:158013:147)
at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:158022:3)
at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:55:30)
at Object.216 (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:70:76)
at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:55:30)
at Object.193 (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:55:70)
at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:55:30)
at webpackJsonpCallback (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:26:23)
at http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:1:1
```

**Ionic Info**

cli packages: (/home/ganeshtikone/.npm/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.11
Cordova Platforms  : none
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
Node              : v10.6.0
npm               : 6.1.0 
OS                : Linux 4.4
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : /home/ganeshtikone/Android/Sdk
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ionic Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "." when importing a service provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51015815/ionic-uncaught-error-cannot-find-module-when-importing-a-service-provider)

Comment: Also see https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/52786

Comment: @SurajRao, please check error stack trace, this one is different. An error is in Vendor.js

Comment: which version of typescript are you using in the project and editor?

Comment: Angular 4 and Ionic 3, Sorry typescript version is 2.6.2, I changed it to latest. 3.0.0

Comment: typescript version..

Comment: Check also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50713430/ionic-3-build-in-prod-mode-cannot-find-module

Comment: Checked not working

Comment: can you add the code of the provider to the question? also package.json?

Comment: While trying the solution you have provided, I delete provider component.
By the way, the issue is resolved by going 3 steps back. by deleting provider, interface and mock, I have created.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and saw that `/umd` was getting appended to my `ionic-angular` imports by my IDE (I think when I moved files around).

For example,

```
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular'
```

was getting changed to

```
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular/umd'
```

Removing the `/umd` fixed the problem.

Comment: Make sure to check **all** `src` files that import from `'ionic-angular'`. My IDE appended `/umd` to every one of them.

Comment: Yes all those are from ionic-angular